# how do we update installed PWA in client's device automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've been recently working on a PWA in ReactJS and I have come to this challenge with automatically updating the installed PWA in user's phone when I update the code and upload it, without having to tell them there's an update.